# XML parsing and dataframe conversion in R

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I have a XML file which I parsed in R and have to read it and convert it into data frame that can subsequently be arranged by the row ID. This the XML file

```
<tags>
<row Id="1" TagName="bayesian" Count="1342" ExcerptPostId="20258" WikiPostId="20257"/>
<row Id="2" TagName="prior" Count="168" ExcerptPostId="62158" WikiPostId="62157"/>
<row Id="3" TagName="elicitation" Count="6"/>
<row Id="4" TagName="normality" Count="191" ExcerptPostId="67815" WikiPostId="67814"/>
<row Id="5" TagName="open-source" Count="13"/>
</tags>
```

I tried using `XMLparse`

```
Tags_data <- xmlParse("../Tags.xml",useInternalNodes = True)
xml_Data <- xmlToList(Tags_data)
ldply(xml_Data,data.frame)
```

Somehow it's giving me errors and the rows are not converted into a data.frame.

Comment: The error I get is "Error in xmlParse(xml, useInternalNodes = True) : 
  object 'True' not found". True should be `TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

The logical value `TRUE` should always be all uppercase in `R`. Moreover, in order to output a data.frame with one row per observation, you should use `rbind` rather than `data.frame` in `ldply` :

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)
xml <- '<tags> <row Id="1" TagName="bayesian" Count="1342" ExcerptPostId="20258" WikiPostId="20257"/>
  <row Id="2" TagName="prior" Count="168" ExcerptPostId="62158" WikiPostId="62157"/>
  <row Id="3" TagName="elicitation" Count="6"/>
  <row Id="4" TagName="normality" Count="191" ExcerptPostId="67815" WikiPostId="67814"/>
  <row Id="5" TagName="open-source" Count="13"/>
  </tags>'

Tags_data <- xmlParse(xml,useInternalNodes = TRUE)
xml_Data <- xmlToList(Tags_data)

ldply(xml_Data,rbind)

  .id Id     TagName Count ExcerptPostId WikiPostId
1 row  1    bayesian  1342         20258      20257
2 row  2       prior   168         62158      62157
3 row  3 elicitation     6          <NA>       <NA>
4 row  4   normality   191         67815      67814
5 row  5 open-source    13          <NA>       <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `xmlAttrsToDataFrame` on the row nodes

```
doc <- xmlParse(xml)
XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(doc["//row"])
  Id     TagName Count ExcerptPostId WikiPostId
1  1    bayesian  1342         20258      20257
2  2       prior   168         62158      62157
3  3 elicitation     6          <NA>       <NA>
4  4   normality   191         67815      67814
5  5 open-source    13          <NA>       <NA>
```